# Text mining in R and return hits

Tags: r

I have a list of genes. I want to search/match each gene against the keyword "nucleus" or "nuclei" or "nuclear" in databases (e.g., AceView) and return a dataframe with all genes with only "true" hits. 
Is it possible in R?
I have some experience in R but surely not an expert. So, any suggestion for packages/scripts that can do it will be very helpful. 
Thanks

A list of genes is given below as an example. My actual list contains >6000 genes.

```
genes = c("PPP1R12A",
"HNRNPDL",
"ARHGEF10",
"SPTBN2",
"SEC16A",
"PLXNB2",
"U2SURP",
"ARHGEF11",
"NPC1",
"SCAMP1",
"SCAMP2",
"ARPC1B",
"ARPC2",
"ARPC3")
```

Comment: I don't see `nucleus` or anything like it in your sample data.  Am I missing anything?

Comment: I am sorry if my question was not clear enough. My data is a list of genes. I want to search, for example, "PLXNB2" AND "nucleus", but for the entire list. In the AceView database you can supply each gene individually but not a list of genes.

Comment: I am a little confused, too. Will `nucleus` appear in the `genes` list? It might be useful to include an expected output. E.G. what genes would you want to see returned from the example provided?

Comment: I am looking of co-occurrence of these terms, "gene names" AND "nucleus". For example, if you enter the gene "CD9" in AceView and then look at the page, the term "nucleus" does not appear anywhere. But if you query "PLXNB2" it does. Does that make sense?

Comment: I have to probably think of a better way to frame the question!

Comment: Still not 100% clear on the request. However, regular expression seems like it might be worth your time. Review `grep`, `grepl`, or the `stringr` package as they might prove useful.